# fetch HTML text from database using php

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to get some data out from a database stored as text usnig php.
The text could be plain text /or html text.

I want to fetch the following fields from the text retrieved from database : City, state, country. 
Here is the example the text could look like

```
country :- US
state   :- Washington
city    :- Bellingham
```

or

```
<table>
<tr><td>country </td><td>US</td></tr>
<tr><td>state</td><td>Washington</td></tr>
<tr><td>city</td><td>Bingen</td></tr>
</table>
```

or same in div tag

I have already done for plain text. 
which I found to be very easy as i found the linebreak (the end of line) and trimmed rest of the text except what was required

But in case of HTML I am facing the problem, how to deal with html text. As there is no line break . Not sure whats the best way to do this if I use strip_tags it returns all text in same line i.e. country us state washington

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want the result to be.

Comment: use regular expressions, just google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do some text processing instead of HTML parsing

```
$input = "<table><tr><td>country </td><td>US</td></tr><tr><td>state</td><td>Washington</td></tr><tr><td>city</td><td>Bingen</td></tr></table>";

$needle = array("<table>", "<tr><td>","</td<td>", "</td</tr>", "</table");
$replacements = array("","",":-","\n","");
$output = str_replace($needle, $replacements, $input);
```

This will give you the same as the text-input.

Comment: thank you for prompt response luckily I managed to do this using same method :) but thanks for confirmation can you help me with div structure?

Answer (score 2):

When you are storing html in databse encode them using HTML_entities(), then to display them use html_entity_decode()

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
$a = htmlentities($orig);
$b = html_entity_decode($a);
echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```